# Display ImagePreview Selected Data from Gallery

Tags: java, android, xml

Selecting the image via the ImageButton then display to image preview in the same position, I can select the images from the gallery but the problem is when I want to display some preview on the same position of ImageButton, but the image preview is from ArrayList items, I can pass the image in one if I will do in the activity_the_grid check the sample image to check the layout and giving me [ java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo] error
[Select Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftf6g.png)

**MainActivity**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_the_grid);
        dgridPreviewImage = findViewById(R.id.the_grid_image_preview); //layout_item
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        SectionedExpandableLayoutHelper sectionedExpandableLayoutHelper = new SectionedExpandableLayoutHelper(this,
                mRecyclerView, this, 3);
        //random data
        ArrayList<Item> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.add(new Item(0));
        arrayList.add(new Item( 1));
        arrayList.add(new Item( 2));
        arrayList.add(new Item( 3));
        arrayList.add(new Item( 4));
        arrayList.add(new Item( 5));
        sectionedExpandableLayoutHelper.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public void itemClicked(Item item) {
        openMediaSelectDialog();
    }

    private void handleImageSelect(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        if (saveContentLocally(intent)) {
            reset();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(mSnapFile));
                dgridPreviewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                mSnapState = TheGrid.SnapState.IMAGE;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Saved the image file, but it doesn't exist!");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Item**

```
public class Item {
private final int id;
public Item( int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
```

**layout_item**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/item_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/item_margin"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/select_snap" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/the_grid_image_preview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside" />

            <com.snapchat.kit.chickencam.SnapVideoView
                android:id="@+id/the_grid_video_preview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/thegrid_share_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear"
        android:layout_below="@id/card_view"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get image from local path

```
object ImagesGallery {

    fun listOfImages(context : Context) :ArrayList<GalleryImage> {

        val cursor : Cursor
        val column_index_data : Int
        val listOfAllImages : ArrayList<GalleryImage> = ArrayList()
        var absolutePathOfImage : String
        val uri : Uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

        val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME)
        val orderBy : String = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN
        cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, orderBy + " DESC")!!
        column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)


        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data)
            listOfAllImages.add(GalleryImage(absolutePathOfImage, false))
        }

        return listOfAllImages
    }
}
```

and then we can call listOfImages() in MainActivity

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
         ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList();

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

          images = ImagesGallery.listOfImages(this)
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but im trying to change the one item on gridview